# Javascript function is only triggered on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

This happens in a Rails 5 application with Ruby 2.3.1. When a dropdown list is changed, I want to collect more information via an ajax request to display below the dropdown list. This functionality works, but only if I load or refreshes the page.

app/assets/javascripts/articles.coffee

```
initGuideline = ->
  $('#article_theme_id').on 'change', (event) ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/themes/guideline",
      type: "GET",
      format: 'js',
      data: {
        theme_id: $("#article_theme_id").val()
      }
$(document).ready initGuideline
$(document).on 'ready page:load', initGuideline
```

The dropdown list is in a form partial, `views/articles/_fields.html.slim`, which is called from `views/articles/new.html.slim` and `views/articles/edit.html.slim`.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'slim'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'will_paginate'
and other gems..
```

assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

When I refresh the page the information is fecthed and displayed. But if I navigate away from the page and navigate back the javascript function is no longer triggered.

The above problem is solved by an answer provided below. The behaviour is caused by Turbolinks and the solution is:

```
$(document).ready initGuideline
$(document).on 'ready turbolinks:load', initGuideline
```

Comment: After the following change, the results are still the same: $(document).ready initGuideline
$(document).on 'page:change', initGuideline

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of turbolinks, please try to load on `page:change` instead of `ready`

OR

try

```
$(document).on 'ready turbolinks:change turbolinks:load'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should have worked fine with Rails 4, but for Rails 5 (with turbolinks 5), you need to use `turbolinks:load` instead of `page:load`.

```
$(document).ready initGuideline
$(document).on 'ready turbolinks:load', initGuideline
```

Please follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) for more details.

Comment: The change above delivers the correct behaviour. Thank you 31piy

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', initGuideline
```

No need to listen for **ready** because **turbolinks:load** is fired on ready